# rosjava installation on macosx results in an error

Tags: osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following these instructions http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/hydro/Installation, at the step when `rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y` is executed
I get

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rosjava_build_tools: No definition of [python-rosinstall-generator] for OS [osx]
```

This error looks similar to [this error](http://answers.ros.org/question/108916/openni_launch-rosdep-on-os-x/).

I checked rosjava_build_tools folder and .rosinstall is missing.
I added rosjava_build_tools to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH following the advice given [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/108916/openni_launch-rosdep-on-os-x/).

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: moving to the next step and calling catkin_make does not produce errors.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166666/rosjava-installation-on-macosx-results-in-an-error/) by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 709 on 2014-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the rosdep rule for the python rosinstall_generator is missing on OSX. You should open a ticket or a pull request against [rosdistro](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro) to fix this.

See the doc on [contributing rosdep rules](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0